# Disconnected closed subgroups of $SO(n)$

Tags: geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $SO(n)$ be the special orthogonal group, i.e., the matrix with determinant $1$ satisfying $AA^{T}=A^{T}A=I$. I am interested in understanding the connectedness of closed subgroups of $SO(n)$, for that, I was looking for examples of disconnected closed subgroups of $SO(n)$ with positive dimension.

Based on the fact that the center of $SO(2n)$ is $\{I,-I\}$ taking any connected closed subgroup $H\leq SO(2n)$ we can produce a disconnected subgroup of the form $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times H$. This is the only example I have found, could it be possible to find a more elaborate example of a disconnected close subgroup of $SO(n)$ with positive dimension?

Lattices are the trivial example in case we do not ask for positive dimension.

Are the disconnected close subgroups of $SO(n)$ with positive dimension all them isomorphic to a product of the form $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times H $ with $H$ a closed subgroup with positive dimension?

Comment: Every Compact Lie group is a closed subgroup of some $U(n)$, which is a closed subgroup of $SO(2n)$. So if there's no constraint on $n$, you can all sorts of examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G\le\mathrm{SO}(m)$ is closed and connected, and $K\le\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is finite, then $G\times K\le\mathrm{SO}(m+n)$ fits the bill. The identity component will be $G$, which has a complementary subgroup $K$ in $H=G\times K$, but in general this isn't true. For instance, consider

$$H=\mathrm{SO}(n)\sqcup i[\mathrm{O}(n)\setminus\mathrm{SO}(n)]\le \mathrm{U}(n)$$

embedded in $\mathrm{SO}(2n)$ when $n$ is odd; here $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ has no complementary subgroup in $H$ - exercise. (Also we can give an alternate description of $H$ with Kronecker products instead of complex numbers if you want.)

In general though, the identity component $H_0$ will be connected and $H\le N_G(H_0)$, so maybe we can cook up a general recipe based on the idea of looking for nontrivial finite subgroups of $N_G(H_0)/H_0$ for closed, connected subgroups $H_0\le\mathrm{SO}(n)$.